# d3.js tree layout: move layout to the left to accommodate new nodes?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm working on a tree layout ([example](http://jsbin.com/okUxAvE/5/edit?js,output)) in which users can collapse and expand branches by clicking on them.

In my example, I've used a too-small container to demonstrate what happens when you click on a child node in a large chart: the children simply overflow the svg container and are hidden from view.

Is there a way to move/animate the whole layout to the left in that case, so that the rightmost node is never hidden? Of course, when the nodes are again collapsed, I'd like the layout to translate back to the right again. The effect I'm looking for is *something* like http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/#19 when you click on the rightmost portion of the graph. The previous nodes fade off to the left. They also come back when you click on the left side.

I know I need to translate the layout itself, but as someone new to d3, I'm not sure of a proper approach to determine when the layout should be translated. e.g. should I look at the rightmost side of every node and check to see if its coordinates are within the width of the container? Where would be the best place to check?

Comment: What you need to manipulate is the `transform` attribute of the top level container, e.g. something like `svg.attr("transform", "translate(-20,0)")`. You can combine this with `.transition()` to make it an animation.

Comment: Just a comment, but the bar graph you are showing isn't actually _moving_ the layout, it's using `.enter` and `.exit` to change the visible data.

Comment: @user1 I realize it's not the same thing, just similar in effect. But you're right.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Actually I meant how to determine when this should happen. I'll edit the question a bit as I don't think it was clear.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I did upvote your comment as it was helpful as well.

Comment: To determine whether you need to move, compare the coordinates of any element you add to the size of the SVG.